# Subview taking different frame size in different initial orientation of device in application launch

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, uialertview

I am designing a custom alert for which I am using a view designed in scene dock as following with the constraints and a drop box link for the story board file https://www.dropbox.com/s/dhk5rrme1j2g89g/Main.storyboard?dl=0-

[image]
[image]

Now I am adding the view by the following code-

```
 @IBAction func forgotpassword(sender: AnyObject)
    {




                                blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Dark)
                blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
                blurEffectView.frame = self.contentview.bounds
                blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth,.FlexibleHeight]


                 AlertVieww.frame = CGRectMake(20, (self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.origin.y)! + (navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)! + 20, blurEffectView.frame.width-40, self.AlertVieww.frame.height)



                AlertVieww.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleHeight,.FlexibleWidth]





            blurEffectView.addSubview(self.AlertVieww)



          [self.scrollview.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: false)]
          self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true

        UIView.transitionWithView(self.view.window!, duration: 1.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromBottom, animations:
            {


                self.contentview.addSubview(self.blurEffectView)



            }, completion: { finished in


                self.scrollview.scrollEnabled = false



        })

    }
```

I am posting the following scenarios along with screen shot of my simmulator -

**1.When the simmulator is in potrait mode when I am going to touch the alert button -**

Simmulator in potrait -

[image]

And then I rotate it to landscape -

[image]

**2.When the simmulator is in landscape mode when I am going to touch the alert button**

Simmulator in landscape -

[image]

Then I rotate it to potrait****(Here is when the problem comes)** -** 
Also my user interaction with both send and cancel button is disabled.

[image]

How to solve the above problem? How to fix the alertview the proper location on the screen. **EDIT** I also tried the most voted answer to my question https://stackoverflow.com/a/34610391/5395919 but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: U can try select your whole subview...pin it in exactly center of the main view with `horizontal/vertical in container` constraint and see again, it works best for me. If u add subview with code, consider make a check and update the frame location when orientation change and reload with `setNeedsLayout ` + `layoutIfNeeded `, your problem is basically the view use postrait frame for landscape frame which wont work

Comment: @Tj3n Can you please provide an answer with some codes so that it may help the readers of your answer as well as me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `true`

**From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) :**

> By default, the property is set to true for any view you
>   programmatically create. If you add views in Interface Builder, the
>   system automatically sets this property to false.

```
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleWidth,.FlexibleHeight]
blurEffectView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true) 

AlertVieww.autoresizingMask = [.FlexibleHeight,.FlexibleWidth]
AlertVieww.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)
```

Comment: Sorry but my last problem still persists i.e after I touch the button in landscape and turn my simmulator right to potrait ,it remains the same.

Comment: Please post full screenshot of each constraint. I think issue is with some constraint

Comment: Please check my question,I have added a screen shot of all constraints. here is a drop box link - https://www.dropbox.com/s/dhk5rrme1j2g89g/Main.storyboard?dl=0

Comment: use https://www.sendspace.com/file/xokjus and dont set frames. Just set constraints of outer view programatically after adding that view. outer view is blurEffectView

Comment: Sorry can you please give a bit coding for that stuff? It would be very helpful.

Comment: Sorry but just google for "Adding constraints programetically swift". I cant help as i have limited knowledge in swift...

Answer (score 0):

Use autlo layout / NSLayoutConstraint for your alert view.
This may help you.

```
You need to set the following constraints.

1. centerX and centerY constraints for center your alert view.
2. Add the space constraint in between "send" and "cancel" buttons.
3. Add the top constraint for your label and textfield.
```

Read the following best tutorial for better understanding.
http://angelovillegas.com/2014/01/31/ios-nslayoutconstraint/

Comment: why to set the constraints programmatically when I have set it in the IB.